# How to eliminate the "smell" of code called "large class"?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring

Help me please to understand how to get rid of code "smell" called "Big class". I have a class in which I create a GUI. I add a panel on the GUI and after that I add some components on that panel. All in all, it has a fairly complex structure. Here is a method in wich I start to create the panel:

```
private static JPanel createTasksMainInfoPanel(JTabbedPane taskTabbedPane) {
JPanel panelForMainInfo = new JPanel();
//some code...
addComponentForMainInfoBox(verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo, new String(),
        createTypeChoicePanel(max, min));
JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
createListenerForOk(ok, fieldForName, fieldForVarQuantity,
        FieldForLimitQuantity, FieldForCritQuantity, max,
        taskTabbedPane);
addComponentForMainInfoBox(verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo, new String(), ok);
panelForMainInfo.add(verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo);
return panelForMainInfo;
}
```

Here I shown only start and end of my method. There are about 50 rows more in the middle. Most of all at the end of the method I call another methods that are also needed for creating my panel. Another problem is that I call these methods with a lot of arguments. So, in result I have long methods with large lists of arguments. And my class in which I create the GUI becomes very large. Is it not better for me to create an individual class for my panel? Then all that I passed in the parameters could make the fields in this class. And it would be possible to allocate more compact methods and without the huge lists of parameters. But I'm not sure that I'm right. I want to add another class, so I want to add new relationships between classes. So, is it possible to move  all the code that is responsible for the establishment of the panel? And is it a good idea?

Comment: It is fairly opinion based. IMO, you should split the whole thing into methods. And call them one by one in the constructor. And you _can_ put them in classes of their own. But you should remember to keep the abstraction level consistent!

Comment: @Sweeper, thank you for your answer! But can I specify some things, please, because my English is not very good? As I can see you suggest two solutions? First solution it is to leave it all in the original class. And I can to turn all local variables into fields of original class? In this case I could to allocate more compact methods in original class and without the huge lists of parameters? Anoher solution it is to put all this variables in their own classes? In this case I could use it in the original class and the original class wil be smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complex topic which really can't be dealt with adequately here. There is a fantastic book by Robert C. Martin called "clean code". It provides step by step examples to refactor a large complex class into smaller simpler classes. I highly recommend you read it.

In general (there are lots of exceptions) good design follows the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) - it should try to do one thing only. In practice it's not always possible to achieve this and it's pretty hard to decide how large 'one thing' should be. In your case the 'one thing' looks like it's creating the components in a panel. Everything not related to creating the panel (e.g. dealing with events associated with the panel) should be in other classes.

Long list of arguments are generally a bad smell. Ask yourself if the list of arguments really represent common context that should be in their own class and passed into the method as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I understand, I could create small class for all components wich I added to my Panel. For example, I could create class MyTextField extends JTextField and so on? Then I can to declare them as fields of original class and use them in all methods of the original class? It looks like a solve of my problem, thank you! But can I specify some things about it? Is creating a class with a lot of fields not bad for memory? And my original class  will have a lot of dependencies. Is it not bad?

Comment: You can hardly loosely couple dependencies of UI components over other UI components. I don't think it's usually worth it... For instance, if you have a `UIForm` component that has a few checkboxes, date pickers and text fields, you probably do not want to start injecting all these into the `UIForm` constructor. Even if you rely on a dependency injection framework it's not worth the effort. However you may want to be able to swap the view controlled by the controller, but that's another story.